# How to implement more complex navigation in PyroCMS?

Tags: php, content-management-system, pyrocms

I am new to PyroCMS 2.1 - I am creating a new template and wondering how to implement the following navigation - can it be done in PyroCMS at all?

```
<ul id="navlist">
                <li id="nav_one"><a id="link_one" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li id="nav_two"><a id="link_two" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
...
</ul>
```

Basically, I need a different set of ID's for each menu item (`li` and `a` elements).

Advanced navigation tag options doesn't help: http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/index.php/modules-and-tags/tag-reference/navigation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like there is a native way to do this in PyroCMS, but you can add a class to each `li` in the navigation section of the admin panel.

If you do decide you really need the id's generated in your templates, you could look at extending the navigation module and widget yourself. You could update the database to include the fields you need, update the navigation module controller and models (and admin panel views) and update the widget to include the fields in the navigation variable.

Good luck!

Comment: There certainly is a way to do this. Checking the docs should answer most questions you have.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you guys hacking the core?!

You can do what you like with the Navigation HTML output but using the [Tag Pair](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/plugins/navigation#tag-pair-usage) syntax.

Gotta love those double tags.

Answer (score -1):

/system/cms/modules/navigation/plugin.php

attributes of anchor

```
$item['url']    `enter code here`= $link['url'];
$item['title']  = $link['title'];
$item['id']  = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($link['title']));
```

I add this lastnew line and search this code line 198 aprox and

add (id="' . $item['id'] . ')

```
$output .= $ident_b . '<' . $tag . ($classes > '' ? ' class="' . $classes . '" id="' . $item['id'] . '">' : '>') . PHP_EOL;
```

before you can use that ...... (in the menu vavigations)

and you css make e.g. if name link is  New Products you use css .new-products{......}